# can I use ajax to call C# code behind method?

Tags: c#, ajax

I know I can use ajax to call web method of web-service.
can I use ajax to call a simple code behind method?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean?? can you extend your question a little??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the WebMethod attribute

[Pagemethods in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4558607/138071)

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can. With a little feature called page methods.

Decorate your codebehind method with the `[WebMethod]` attribute and you can call it from your  page via javascript and within your WebForms html.

See this:
http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Using_Page_Methods_in_ASPNET_AJAX.aspx

Also see [how to use JQuery to call asp.net page methods.](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. See [here](http://www.rajeeshcv.com/2008/10/aspnet-ajax-calling-server-side-methods-from-client-side/). It requires putting a `ScriptManager` tag on your page, and decorating your methods with an attribute.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with or without a script manager. I would suggest looking into the ajax method in jQuery (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) as well as these links:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

http://www.infinitelooping.com/blog/2011/05/20/using-jquery-ajax-to-call-web-methods/

http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Comment: 2/3 links broken.