# How to call a codebehind function using javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I'm trying to call this code behind function :

```
protected void Insert(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            blah blah blah code
            this.BindGrid();
        }
```

While in the .aspx file I've got my java function which looks like this:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Call Button Click" Style="display:none" OnClick="Insert" />
<asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClientClick="return Validate();" Width="100" />

        <script type="text/javascript">
                function Validate()
                {
                    var id = document.getElementById("txtStudentID").value;
                    Number(id);
                    var fn = document.getElementById("txtFirstName").value;
                    String(fn);
                    var ln = document.getElementById("txtLastName").value;
                    String(ln);
                    var cls = document.getElementById("txtClass").value;
                    String(cls);
                    var rn = document.getElementById("txtRollNumber").value;
                    Number(rn);
                    My code blah blah blah
                    document.getElementById("Button2").click();
                    PageMethods.Insert(onSuccessMethod, onFailMethod);
                };
          </script>
```

I need the Insert to work when I press the button add (the one that's visible).
I'm not sure if my logic is correct or if there's a better way to it.
It'd be much appreciated if someone knew hot can I call the Insert fonction from my javascript. I've tried a couple of stuff from google but none of them seem to work.
thanks in advance

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/a/4558607/2558060

Comment: Check the following urls, it will help http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Call-Code-Behind-Server-Side-function-from-Client-Side-code-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/180355/Calling-a-code-behind-function-from-JavaScript

Comment: Well I think I'll have to go through ajax since I can't change my protected method into a public static.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Ok It turns out to be a simple problem of Onclick and OnClientClick.
OnClientClick is the function that executes first and once completed goes to the OnClick fonction. At the end of the day here's what I ended up with:
Code behind :

```
public void Validate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      boring code blah blah blah
}
```

Here's the aspx code

```
    <script id="validity" type="text/javascript">

        function Validate() {

             Blah blah blah boring code
        }
    </script>
    <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" OnClientClick="return Validate();" OnClick="Validate"
            Text="Add" Width="100" />
```

I use the onclientclick to execute the javascript based validation. and once completed I ececute the server side dataupload. Seems very basic once completed. I hope it helps others in future

Answer (score 2):

You may try this :

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"CallMyFunction","Validate()",true);
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, could you tell me if I add this inside my foction or in the beginning of the code (aspx.cs)?

Comment: well it's not working, the page just reloads doesn't even enter the Insert fonction. :(

Comment: add this inside the event method of your button, it should works

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't. Or I'm just doing it wrong somehow

Answer (score 1):

We can use [WebMethod] for the method which we want to call from JavaScript. And that should be a static method as per my knowledge.
And we can call that method from JavaScript by using

```
PageMethods.MethodNameOnCodeBehindClass()
```

So is it possible for your scenario to create a static method which can call your desired method.

Comment: That was my first thought, but I it seems I can't even manage to call the public static methode from Javascript. let alone call the protected from the public static.

Comment: Thats we can do buddy.. If you are agree to call a public static method from Javascript . because recently i have done the same implementation. BTW i didt get your comment :p, what exactly u were trying to say..

Answer (score 1):

You can also try:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this,Gettype(this),"","validate();",true);
```