# Call server side method from JavaScript in C#

Tags: javascript, c#

I want to call a C# server method from JavaScript. In JavaScript function alert is coming but not calling the server method.

Here is my code. This is the server side method:

```
public void ReloadData()
{
     //here is the code
}
```

Here is the client side function:

```
function GetData() {
alert("Function called");
PageMethods.ReloadData();
}
```

Now, here the `getdata` function is called and alert is also coming but in server side method is not called. [I have seen by doing in debug mode.]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pagemethods in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313532/pagemethods-in-asp-net)

Comment: nope this is not duplicate because here javascript is called but not going in server side method

Comment: Read it again. End of day, you are using client-side script to make a request to some server resource.`Web Forms` has `PageMethods` as an _option_ that you can use, and needs some setup.

Comment: @s.k.Soni Are you using an asp.net ?

Comment: Yes @roxy'pro....

Answer (score 1):

I believe you will have to use AJAX for this.  Have a look here: https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-ASPNet-WebMethod-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx

ReloadData will be a webmethod in your code behind and will look something like this:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public void ReloadData()
{
     //here is the code
}
```

Then from the client side you will do something like this:

```
function GetData() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "CS.aspx/ReloadData",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: OnSuccess,
        failure: function(response) {
            alert(response.d);
        }
    });
```

}

`CS.aspx` is the name of your webpage.

Following on from your comment below; if you did not want to use JQuery then your Javascript code would look something like this:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'CS.aspx/ReloadData');
xhr.onload = function() {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
        alert('Successful');
    }
    else {
        alert('Request failed.  Returned status of ' + xhr.status);
    }
};
xhr.send();
```

Comment: is there possible to do with javascript?

Comment: @s.k.Soni you use JavaScript to make the AJAX call. The JavaScript code runs in the client browser, whle the C# code is on your server. HTTP (AJAX) is how the two environments communicate.

Comment: @s.k.Soni, I have updated the code.  Are you asking if it is possible to do this without JQuery?