# How to pass values from Javascript to code behind code function?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am not able to pass a value from Javascript to code behind.
The result value is always undefined.

I have attached the code:

```
    <input id="Button2" type="button" value="FunctionCall" onclick="CallingServerSideFunction()" />
<script type="text/javascript">

    function CallingServerSideFunction() {
        alert("start");
        var result =PageMethods.Add(1,2);
        alert(result);
    }

</script>

</form>
```

My cs code:
     public static int Add(int x, int y)

```
    {
        int k = x + y;
        return k;
    }
```

Help me out with this!

Comment: Check the accepted answer in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313532/pagemethods-in-asp-net) post

Answer (score 0):

It happen because the **PageMethods** calling asynchronously so the alert showing before the web method result assign in variable result.

I hope below code will help.

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function CallingServerSideFunction() {
        PageMethods.Add(1, 2, OnSuccess);
    }
    function OnSuccess(response, userContext, methodName) {
        alert(response);
    }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<input id="Button2" type="button" value="FunctionCall" onclick="CallingServerSideFunction()" />
```

C#:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod()]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
public static int Add(int x, int y)
{
    int k = x + y;
    return k;
}
```